How can I manage multiple hostnames (domains, subdomains) from a single source with CodeIgniter 4
I have an application that I want to run with multiple subdomains. I plan to develop this application for a long time and I have a lot of active users. In order to avoid more confusion in the future, I want to make each update from a single source instead of doing it with different hosts. Currently, the application can use a single database for each subdomain, but I cannot run a single code as source code. The method of running different subdomains by creating folder copies shown in the CI4 documentation does not provide the flexibility I want.
In short, how can we run multiple subdomains with a single source code. We can dynamically change the baseURL in Config/App.php. we can pull specific information such as logo, url, header etc. from the database for each subdomain. We can run the project on the main domain without any problems, but we get errors in subdomains.
I get this error when redirecting to subdomain.

Start by flipping the question on its head: what do you want to be different for the different subdomains? I don't know anything about CodeIgniter, but PHP itself doesn't care about the URL it's accessed on at all; it just gives you that information for you to make your own decisions based on.

Actually, I made the architecture thinking this way. But CI4 gives an error in subdomains while running the main domain. Information is given in the documentation for this, but the information there does not fulfil the function I want. Unfortunately, this is the point that blocks me.

Clicking [edit] and adding some more details about that error, and the configuration you've tried, will probably make it more likely someone can help you. At the moment, the question comes across as quite general and vague.

You're right. Thank you very much, I'll edit it immediately.

Please do not post images of code/data/errors

Please please post your config file so that i can edit in it with  example code posted below

you can easily do that when working with multiple domains like example below
You have to change variable values according to the current working domain
we have did same this for more than 10 different domains and subdomains pointed to same directory with dynamic config variables. also make sure the each domain and subdomain is pointed to same folder in apache domain config else this will give error.

 <?php
       
       namespace Config;

      use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;

     class Customconfig extends BaseConfig
     {
       public $siteName ;
       public $siteEmail;
       public $url;
       public $db; 
          function __construct(){
                $app_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 

       if($app_domain=='subdomain.example.com'){
           $this->siteName  = 'My Great Site';
           $this->siteEmail = 'webmaster@example.com';
           $this->url ="https://subdomain.example.com";
           $this->db="db1";
            //// other config variables
       }
       
       if($app_domain=='subdomain2.example.com'){
           $this->siteName  = 'My Great Site 1';
           $this->siteEmail = 'webmaster2@example.com';
           $this->url ="https://subdomain2.example.com";
           $this->db="db2";
            //// other config variables
       }
       /// and so no ......
          }
     }


    $config = new Customconfig();
    
    $siteName  = $config->siteName;
    $siteEmail = $config->siteEmail;
    $url       = $config->url;
    $db        = $config->db;
      
 ?>


